# How can I get Chart Type from Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have to create a dashboard with exact charts from azure application insights metrics. Using the Azure Application Insights REST API metric data is available but not the chart type.
Is there any other way to get the chart type selected by a user for displaying metrics.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a little more? You're using rest api to get the metrics data, then how to build the chart? You want to use rest api to get the chart type as well?

Comment: Using the rest api I get the metrics data but I also need to know the chart type as well so that I can build the same chart in my application. 
For example if Chart type for 'Availability' metric is Line chart then I should know  this information as well so that I can build Line chart for 'Availability' in my application.

Comment: I'm not very clear. If you get the metrics, you can use your own code to build any type of chart. The chart type in application insights(in azure portal) is defined by Kusto query language.

Comment: I need to create a dashboard in my application which is replica of metrics and their charts from app insights. So if I don't know the chart type I may end up building a different chart than what is being displayed on the portal.

Comment: This makes it clear. But can you attach a screenshot where the metrics and chart comes from? Previously, I thought you used rest api to query the metrics from app insights database.

Comment: I've used the rest api to query the metrics from app insights database. But is there any way using which I can get the chart type also for a metric.